# Angular 4 get height of element on components parent

Tags: angular

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ca9qn?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts)

I have a super simple parent component with a child component.

How can I get the height of the parent div from the child component.

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-comp',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() parent: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild("self")
  self: ElementRef;

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    //console.log(this.parent.nativeElement.clientHeight);
    console.log(this.self.nativeElement.offsetTop);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the 'AfterViewInit' lifecycle hook bc the view isn't fully initialized in NgOnInit and heights won't be calculated yet.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let parentHeight = this.self.nativeElement.offsetParent.clientHeight;
}
```

A better way might be to write a directive that you can place on the parent that outputs the width with an event emitter, and then send that width to the child as an input. I don't always have great luck reading calculated properties off of a 'offsetParent' on a nativeElement.

Edit - using the parent as input

```
@Input() parent : HTMLElement;

ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log(this.parent.clientHeight);
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses 'self' and 'offsetParent'. My real code is more complex so I wanted to use the `@Input() parent: ElementRef;`. Is that possible

Comment: Sure - just change the type of your Input to "HTMLElement" and then you can access the height without needing the nativeElement object. I'll update my answer